# Windows 11 PC waking up from hibernation with unknown wake reason

Tags: windows-11, power, hibernate, event-viewer

This problem has been driving me mad for the past few months. Almost every time I put my computer into hibernation mode for the night it immediately boots back up. After a few times, it will eventually stay hibernating, but I always have to do it two or three times. I've disallowed my mouse, ethernet adapter, and Wifi Card from waking up the computer and disabled wake timers. I've explored event viewer and found that the wake reason in Power-Troubleshooter is this:

```
The system has returned from a low power state.

Sleep Time: ‎2024‎-‎02‎-‎14T01:35:04.973093300Z
Wake Time: ‎2024‎-‎02‎-‎14T01:35:52.857300700Z

Wake Source: Unknown
```

As you can see, it decides to boot up about a minute after hibernation. I am on Windows 11 and in a dual-boot with a modified windows 11 installation (Revision OS), which I use for gaming. None of the other solutions I've found on this platform work for me.

Comment: It appears it is in Sleep mode, not Hibernation. In true hibernation, the processor is **off** and cannot wake by itself. https://www.ionos.com/digitalguide/server/configuration/windows-11-hibernate-mode/

Comment: If you believe you have enabled true Hibernation , update Power drivers and BIOS (UEFI) ..   Hibernation:  Power Options , select Change what the power buttons do,  Change settings that are currently unavailable.  Hibernate settings are there.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik I guess whats happening is that its returning to the normal power state before the processor shuts off. I'm not sure why in Event Viewer it says it wakes up 50 seconds later because its more like 15.

Comment: @John My power drivers are probably being updated by Windows update right? I can see if my bios needs an update from my PC manufacturer's (Dell's) website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating my BIOS appears to have worked, at least for now.